# UITableview is not scrolling if less tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to scroll tableview even there is no data at initial. to track `- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

If there are more rows than visible area of UITableView cell, then only scrolling (vertically) is enable. but I'm trying table, in which there will be zero row at begining.

Note * I had placed UITableView from IB

in https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh , it is working even there are less rows.

but one weird thing is, if I get back to view (contains UITableView contains less row) , now it works even after less row.

Please let me know, if anybody doesnot understand my problem

Comment: i does not understand your problem

Comment: ok, :) I cannot scroll UITableView if there are less rows , But I want to scroll even there are less rows  , did you face that sorts?

Comment: No. Is there any problem the table view doesn't scroll when there are no cells that are not visible ? Is that your problem

Comment: if there are no Cells, then UITableVIew is not scrolling, But I want to enable scrolling even there is no any UITableViewCell on UITableView. Why I want to make enable is, I want to refresh table same like in facebook app if user scroll downs UITableView

Comment: the only reason for that I see is that the table view's `bounces` property is set to `NO`, but it should be `YES`by default, give it a try

Comment: Are you sure? In XCode, Bounces is on by default in IB. I'm using XCode 4

Comment: oh ok I see, you should try writing another more precise question. I see a way to do this by putting just one special cell at top. I am sure that by default it is `YES` so I said it, but I didn't really believed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to take any credits by myself.
all credit goes to [Vince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756245/vince)

If I set Bounces property of UITableView on IB, it is not actually setting YES for less rows,

after I do,`[self.table setBounces:YES];`on viewDidLoad , scroll is enable even if there is no rows, ;)

thank you vince again,

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for that bounce effect where you can drag on the table and it rubber bands a bit you can set `myTable.alwaysBouncesVertical = YES;`  If you are looking for the ability to actually scroll with blank cells showing up you will have to actually specify blank cells in your `cellForRowAtIndex:` method.

Answer (score 0):

From your message and comments, I am interpreting that you want to enable scrolling on a UITableView when the number of cells is equal to 0.

Let me attempt to answer your question with a question: What are you scrolling if there are 0 cells?

The reason the scroll does not work is because there is no content to scroll. Your UITableView, when it has 0 cells, will not scroll because it has nothing to replace the data that you're trying to move.

**"Why I want to make enable is, I want to refresh table same like in facebook app if user scroll downs UITableView"**
This is not default functionality for a UITableView. This is custom functionality that has to be programmed, this is why the app is not doing what you expect it to be doing.

Comment: little right :), did you remember on Facebook app? if I scroll down UITableView, it starts to refresh table, Same I'm trying to do, I'm trying to connect to server, get data and populate table again. In my case there are only few row (let's say 2) at initial, I want to refresh data from server after scrolling down the UITableView (same as in Facebook app ) :) thank you ColdLogic for interest

Comment: sorry ColdLogic, it is fixed, don't need to do custom program . I really appreciate time you had given. thank you